# Dinic Algorithm with limited vertices

Tags: max-flow

Is it possible to construct a graph with 5 to 10 vertices for which the Dinic-Algorithm finds exactly |V|-1 blocking flows, and if so what does it look like?

Comment: Dinc Algorithm + Nauty geng = answer in a few seconds
http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/